# CMS architecture - PHP

Tags: php, content-management-system

I want to build CMS soon, and I want to know how to build it structurally.. I mean.. All in one class? or somthing like for page = class, gallery = another class.. etc.

I just begginer so I dont know the perffect  architecture.

Thank you.

Comment: hehe another CMS. If he wants to he should although I think he should start a little simpler without much programming experience.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471940/why-does-every-man-and-his-dog-want-to-code-a-blogging-engine

Comment: If there was a "perfect architecture", the answer you seek would be long enough to fill a book.

Comment: Can you provide your own insights for this question? It's been a while since you asked this question and I'm interested to know what are the most important aspects you learned from your own experience with writing a custom CMS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to build CMS soon, and I want to know how to build it structurally

I would advice you to look at the source code of other open source CMS systems like for example joomla! you can learn a lot by looking at other peoples source.

> I just begginer so I dont know the perffect architecture.

writing a CMS is a complicated task and I would start writing something simpler first like a simple blog(also see video below maybe improving it a little bit) if I stood in your shoes. You should learn to use PHPUnit(TDD) with it and a SCM-system like git/svn to do it properly. Also you should learn things like MVC(see video below).

> All in one class?

Hell no. I would advice you to watch the screencast [create a blog in 20 minutes](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/) from codeigniter(sit back and relax). It will teach you the MVC structure which is a must and guide you a little bit in how to write your CMS. Easy to begin and it will make you a better programmer(MVC is important).

Answer (score 0):

First evaluate why you need to make another CMS.

I'd say spend some time with at least 3 different CMSes(or CMFs), and then I'd say spend some time with some of the current frameworks.

then reevaluate why you're planing on doing a cms in the first place. By the sounds of you don't really know what you're getting yourself into, and if the term MVC is new to you, spend a bit more time on smaller project before undertaking a CMS. It if is a matter of not having features that you desire, you can try some of the more open [CMFs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_frameworks) (like modx)